# Scheme - Optional arguments and default values

Tags: arguments, scheme, racket, optional-parameters

I'm currently looking into Scheme, and the way I have understood it, procedures can take an arbitrary number of arguments.

I have been trying to play around with this, but I'm struggling to grasp the concept.

For instance, say I want to write a welcome message, based on information provided by the user.

If user provides a first and last name, the program shout write:

```
Welcome, <FIRST> <LAST>!
;; <FIRST> = "Julius", <LAST>= "Caesar"
Welcome, Julius Caesar!
```

Otherwise, the program should refer to a default value, specified as:

```
Welcome, Anonymous Person!
```

I have the following outline for my code, but struggling with how to finalise this.

```
(define (welcome . args)
  (let (('first <user_first>/"Anonymous")
        ('last <user_last>/"Person"))
    (display (string-append "Welcome, " first " " last "!"))))
```

Example usage:

```
(welcome) ;;no arguments
--> Welcome, Anonymous Person!
(welcome 'first "John") ;;one argument
--> Welcome, John Person!
(welcome 'first "John" 'last "Doe") ;;two arguments
--> Welcome, John Doe!
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

In Racket, the way to do this would be using [keyword arguments](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._keyword-args%29). You can define a function with keyword arguments my writing `#:keyword argument-id` when declaring the arguments:

```
(define (welcome #:first first-name #:last last-name)
  (display (string-append "Welcome, " first-name " " last-name "!")))
```

Which you can call like this:

```
> (welcome #:first "John" #:last "Doe")
Welcome, John Doe!
```

However, what you want is to make them optional. To do that, you can write `#:keyword [argument-id default-value]` in the argument declaration.

```
(define (welcome #:first [first-name "Anonymous"] #:last [last-name "Person"])
  (display (string-append "Welcome, " first-name " " last-name "!")))
```

So that if you don't use that keyword in a certain function call, it is filled with the default value.

```
> (welcome)
Welcome, Anonymous Person!
> (welcome #:first "John")
Welcome, John Person!
> (welcome #:first "John" #:last "Doe")
Welcome, John Doe!
> (welcome #:last "Doe" #:first "John")
Welcome, John Doe!
```

Comment: This does not take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: I wasn't intending to make it take an arbitrary number of arguments; if you need that you can write `(define (welcome #:first first-name #:last last-name . rest-args) ...)`

Answer (score 3):

@Alex Knauth's answer is great. That's something I didn't know about.

Here's an alternative, though it's not quite as flexible

```
(define (welcome (first "Anonymous") (last "Person"))
  (displayln (string-append "Welcome, " first " " last "!")))
```

This works pretty nicely with your basic requirements

```
> (welcome)
Welcome, Anonymous Person!
> (welcome "John")
Welcome, John Person!
> (welcome "John" "Doe")
Welcome, John Doe!
```

However, Alex's solution has two distinct advantages.

1. The arguments can be called in either order
2. The last name can be specified without the first name

Comment: Your answer could be improved by defining `(define welcome
  (lambda args
    (string-append
     "Welcome, "
     (or (assq-ref args 'first) "Anonymous")
     " "
     (or (assq-ref args 'last) "Person"))))` and then calling `(welcome '(first . "John") '(last . "Doe"))`.

Comment: You should submit this as another answer to the question. It's a nice alternative, but if I wanted to keyword the arguments, I would probably just use Alex's solution. Thanks for sharing ^_^